# Citadel Mail Server Rejecting SMTP clients

Tags: outlook, raspberry-pi, smtp, debian-based, smtp-auth

I setup a Citadel Mail Server on a RPI 3B+. I have DNS setup, port forwarding, and port open on firewall. When I enter through the webmail portal, I can send and receive mail just fine. The issue that I am having is with mail clients.

I can use IMAP and POP just fine to receive mail with my credentials just fine also.

Whenever I try to send mail using a client (tried a couple different ones), it fails on sending. Right now, I am not using SSL until I get it working on the basic port. The devices I am trying are local devices that do not pass a firewall. With sender authentication turned on, it always says invalid login even though the same login works for IMAP and POP. Turned off it says it requires a login.

For some reason it rejects logins to send mail even if they are a valid user on the system. Works 100% though with the same user on the webmail portal.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Let me know if more info is required.

I originally asked this question on SuperUser(since when I was going to aks here it directed me there due to it being software instead of code), but never got a reply and found other questions concerning Citadel here.

Also, I will add a bit more info. The original admin account can login fine, but gets and error 530 because it will not let me add an internet email address to that user. I add it and hit save. It goes back to blank everytime. Rebooting does nothing. Adding more users gives original result of not being able to login for smtp.

All users have the checkbox selected to allow internet email and have a internet email address, besides the original admin who I cannot enter an internet email address.

Also, same result for ports 25 and 587 both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully an answer, but since nobody is responding to this I will add the conclusion I got to when doing more research. Uninstall Citadel and find a tutorial for Postfix and Dovecot for RPI. I have it mostly working, but have a bit of work to do with StartTLS.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for this answer but...

It seems that Citadel will reject SMTP requests on any account that has a password greater than 19 characters. Both IMAP and POP still work for longer passwords.